# Почему не выводится текст на сайте?

Tags: html, css

Почему то сама надпись "Онлайн курсы Алексея светлого" не выводится, зато изменения в классе "intro" появляются, если, допустим, поменять цвет фона. И если надпись засунуть в "header", то она появляется.

```css
/* http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ 2. v2.0 | 20110126
  License: none (public domain)
*/
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed,
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup,
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  font: inherit;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure,
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
  display: block;
}
body {
  line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
  list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
  quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
  content: '';
  content: none;
}
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}
header {
    background-color: #363636;
    position: fixed;
    height: 60px;
    width: 100%;
}
#logo {
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    float: left;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
}

.headertext {
    display: flex;
    float: left;
    align: center;
    margin-top: 22px;
    font-size: 16px;
}
.piec{margin-left: 200px;}
.headertext1 {margin-left: 50px; margin-bottom: 1;}
a {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover {
    color: #43f749;
}
a:visited {
    color: white;
}
/* Здесь не выводится текст */
intro {
    background-color: #363636;
    weight: 100%;
    height: 400px;
}
.intro p {
    font-color: white;
    font-size: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="ru">

<head>
    <meta name="keywords", content="уроки игры на гитаре, гитара, как научиться играть на гитаре">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Школа игры на гитаре</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <header bgcolor="#1f1f1f">
    
        <a href="home.html"><img id="logo" src="logo.png"></a>
        
        <div class="headertext">
            <div class="piec">
                <a class="headertext1" href="aboutme">ОБО МНЕ</a>
                <a class="headertext1" href="metod">МОЙ МЕТОД</a>
                <a class="headertext1" href="forwho">ДЛЯ КОГО</a>
            </div>
            <div class="piec">
                <a class="headertext1" href="price">СТОИМОСТЬ</a>
                <a class="headertext1" href="reviews">ОТЗЫВЫ</a>
                <a class="headertext1" href="contacts">КОНТАКТЫ</a>
            </div>
        </div>  
    </header>

    <div class="intro">
            <p>Онлайн курсы Алексея Светлого</p>    <!-- Этот текст не выводится -->
    </div>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: искренне хочется верить, что с игрой на гитаре у вас не так все ужасно как с версткой...

Comment: Во-первых, `intro {` => `.intro {`, во-вторых, `weight: 100%;` - такого нет, есть font-weight, В-третьих, поскольку у блока header `position: fixed;` (чтобы вверху был всегда надо ещё добавить `top: 0;`) то он перекрывает ваш текст, для .intro добавив отступ который равен высоте блока header (`margin-top: 60px;`) вы его увидите под блоком header

Comment: Спасибо большое!  Я просто только учусь, у меня это первый сайт только